# Call a function on created window in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, window

I have a window, from which I can open another one and there I'd like to call a function from the first window that affects first window itself. How can I do so?

It doesn't work that way

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view/MyWindow.fxml"));
    loader.load();

    MyWindowController MyWindow = loader.getController();
    MyWindow.someFunction();
```

It only works, If I call a function which affects a NEW window, like that

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view/MyWindow.fxml"));
    loader.load();

    MyWindowController MyWindow = loader.getController();
    MyWindow.someFunction();
    Parent root;
    root = loader.getRoot();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("View employee");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
    stage.setResizable(false);
```

Comment: window 2 will need a reference to window 1 and call a method on it

Comment: In the first example, the controller is for a UI that is never displayed (you just call `loader.load()` and discard the result, and never do anything with `loader.getRoot()`). So you can never possibly see the results of whatever `someFunction()` does. (It has nothing to do with using a *new* window; if you display the root of the FXML in an existing window it will work too. But if you don't display it anywhere, what do you expect to see?)

Comment: @James_D but how can I actually display the root of the FXML in an existing window so that I'll be able to see `someFunction()` working?

Comment: Either `someExistingScene.setRoot(root);` or `someExistingStage.setScene(new Scene(root));` or `someExistingPane.getChildren().add(root);` (where `someExistingPane` is already displayed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I created a reference of the 1st window `parentStage`

and then displayed the root of the FXML in parentStage

```
Parent root;
root = loader.getRoot();
parentStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
```

Seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a misunderstanding of what FXMLLoader, Stages, and Scenes do.

The Window itself is the Stage and it´s contents are Scene(s) (potentially multiple) and those Scenes have Controllers that well control them. **You will have to pass the Controller of the Scene you want to modify to the Controller of the Scene that should do the modification** at some point in time.

After `loader.load();` you do not yet have a Window and you cannot get access to the existing Windows that way either. You have a variable that might be used to create a new Scene in the form of `Parent root`. That´s it.

**Alternatively**, you can look into **JavaFX´s ObservableValues and Lists** that might just do what you want to achieve. Instead of passing around Controllers, you´d then create a Static (or Singleton) DataSourceController that gives access to the ObservableValue and you just use is in both Scenes and it will update the other. Depends on what the method is supposed to do to the other Scene.

Comment: A lot of what you say here is not correct. A window cannot have multiple scenes. A controller is not associated with a scene; it is associated with a root element that is loaded from an FXML file. A scene could potentially contain any number of UI structures loaded from FXML files, each with their own controllers.